# How to use google maps with both IOS and Android while using Expo

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-native, expo

I need to use google maps for both IOS and android for a `react-native` expo app.
I found the `react-native-maps` library that makes it easy to use maps, but it renders the default IOS map for IOS. There are some tutorials out there that show you how to integrate google maps to IOS, but those are plain react-native apps created by `react-native` init and not expo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We used the one from Expo for a project last year which is react-native-maps under the hood.
It worked fine for us.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view

Answer (score 6):

Adding to the answer above. to use google map in expo for both platform ios and android you need to do it like this

```
import {MapView} from 'expo'
<MapView 
    provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    initialRegion={this.state.region} 
    showCompass={true} 
    rotateEnabled={false}
    showUserLocation={true} 
    style={css.map} />
```